# Как изменить пароль автозаполнения браузера?

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, форма, пароль

Пользователь изменил свой пароль на сайте. При выходе с сайта и дальнейшей попыткой войти в него, форма автоматически заполняется его email'ом и паролем, который уже не будет соответствовать правильному, что может ввести его в заблуждение. Как можно изменить данные автозаполнения (не через настройки) с помощью php или javascript?

Comment: да вроде при вводе правильного пароля он обновится - даже броузер сам спросит - Обновить пароль ?

Comment: Да, действительно, при изменении пароля, например, gmail'a, выдает сообщение: "Обновить пароль для этого сайта в сервисе google chrome?"; приходиться менять в настройках пароли автозаполнения или ставить  атрибут autocomplete="off", так как данной окно не появляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отключения автозаполнения существует атрибут `autocomplete="off"` (см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx)

Однако, многие браузеры не поддерживают его для типа `password` (см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers/21348793#21348793). Попробуйте устанавливать этот атрибут для логина.